# How to remove a specific linting highlight in VS Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

sometimes the python linter i use (either pylint or mypy) highlight things that aren't an issue.

id like to know if it is possible to ignore this specific highlight. 
i just want to remove the highlight on specific places is it possible ?

(im not asking to completely remove the linter, just remove the highlight at some places that's all)

Answer (score 0):

In general the `# noqa` command should disable linters for that line, but each tool has their own specific way as well. For instance, mypy supports `# type: ignore`.

Comment: `pylint` has `# pylint: disable=linter-warning` where `linter-warning` is the name of the lint warning on that line, e.g `bad-continuation`.